# What are "correlated" subqueries, and why is it that we should avoid them if possible?

Tags: sql, database

I looked it up online and it seems to be that we should avoid them because they run slow or something?

Comment: A subquery condition contains an outer table reference. Not always bad.

Answer (score 2):

A correlated subquery is a subquery where that connects to the outer query, typically via a correlation clause in the `where`.  A generic example would be:

```
select a.*,
       (select count(*)
        from b
        where b.a_id = a.a_id
--------------^ correlation clause
       ) as b_count
from a;
```

Why should you avoid them?  That's like asking "When did you stop beating your spouse?"  It is the wrong question.  There is no reason to avoid them.

As with all SQL constructs, sometimes correlated subqueries perform poorly.  Surprisingly often, though, they are the *fastest* way to implement the desired logic.

Some misinformed people have generalized that they are always bad, probably because those people don't understand how SQL optimizers work.

Comment: +1 for "Surprisingly often, though, they are the fastest way to implement the desired logic." I'm using CSQs in place of COUNT DISTINCT, and they are much faster in my scenario. It seems that (in MS SQL Server at least), if you have more than 6 or 8 COUNT DISTINCTS in the same query, even with heaps of RAM, it suddenly slows down massively (for some reason Bill Gates isn't telling!). Yet, replacing them with CSQs stays fast, even with 16 of them in the same query.